# Referencing asynchronous tasks in a c# dictionary

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I've come across the problem regarding asynchronous tasks in a dictionary in a couple programs now, and I can't wrap my head around how to solve it.

I have an asynchronous task that looks like this:

```
MessageEventArgs.Channel.SendMessage("somestring");
```

`MessageEventArgs` is a class from a 3rd party library that I declare statically at the start of my program:

```
public static MessageEventArgs meargs;
```

The program listens for events in an IRC channel and does actions based on text commands. Rather than have a giant switch statement for each command, I wanted to make a dictionary that matched the string to the method. Not all are simply sending messages, so I can't just store the string to send. It looks like this:

```
public static Dictionary<string, Task> myDict= new Dictionary<string, Task>()
{
    {"!example", MessageEventArgs.Channel.SendMessage("HelloWorld") }
}
```

In Main(), I call:

```
MessageReceived += async (s,e) => 
{
     meargs = e;
     await myDict[e.Message.Text];
}
```

What I've come to realize is that when the dictionary is instantiated, it tries to call SendMessage, as it is an async task. MessageEventArgs isn't instantiated until after, so it throws an exception. Is there a way to go about storing a reference to these functions in a dictionary? I found solutions using delegates, but they didn't seem to work with `void` methods, and `async` methods (to my knowledge) can only return `void` or `Task`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried 'new'ing the SendMessage instances when you initialize myDict?

Comment: Are you sure that you should be keeping the `MessageEventArgs` around as a static variable like that?  Its name makes me think that it's a subclass of `EventArgs`, which is sent to you each time an event happens. I haven't ever really encountered a situation where it is a good idea to keep those around as long lived instances.

Comment: @JustinR.I haven't tried that, but I'll give it a go.

Comment: @BradleyUffner You're right, actually. Totally missed that. I'll get rid of that and find another way to call SendMessage

Comment: Is the signature of the "action" of the Task - i.e. the method that the Task will actually execute - the same for all tasks?  If so please share it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were writing this, I would create an `IrcCommand` class with a virtual `ExecuteCommand` function.  Then create a subclass for every distinct command I wanted to be able to run.  Each subclass would override the `ExecuteCommand` function with the logic needed to invoke the command. `ExecuteCommand` could take an argument of type `Channel` corresponding the the channel to invoke the command.

At startup I would create a `Dictionary<string, IrcCommand>` that was populated with a `Key` of the command text, and a `Value` of a new instance of the subclass implementing that command.

When a command comes in I would pull the `IrcCommand` instance from the dictionary with the matching key and call the `ExecuteCommand` function on it, passing in the `Channel` the command was received from.

---

It could happen something like this.  I don't actually have visual studio open to verify my syntax, so I may have a few errors in here.

An implementation of some commands:

```
public class ExampleCommand : IrcCommand
{
    public override void ExecuteCommand(Channel channel)
    {
        channel.SendMessage("Hello World");
    }
}

public class DisconnectCommand : IrcCommand
{
    public override void ExecuteCommand(Channel channel)
    {
        channel.Disconnect();
    }
}
```

---

Registering commands at application start:

```
private void RegisterCommands()
{
    _commands.add("!example", new ExampleCommand());
    _commands.add("!disconnect", new DisconnectCommand());
}
```

---

Executing the command when received:

```
_commands(commandText).ExecuteCommand(e.channel);
```

Comment: I added some more example code, including a command that does more than send text, for you that should give you a better idea of what I'm talking about.

Comment: This was perfect. It's a little more work to get it set up, but my Program.cs is so much cleaner now, and this will make it easy to add new commands in the future. Thank you!

Comment: Just be careful with this implementation that you don't store any kind of state in the individual `IrcCommand`.  Since there is only ever one instance of each command, they would all share that state.  If you needed to store state, that pattern could be modified so that that command dictionary stores the `Type` of the `IrcCommand` to execute, and then you would use reflection, specifically `Activator.CreateInstance` to create a new command instance each time.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of creating the tasks immediately, store factories:

```
public static Dictionary<string, Func<Task>> myDict= new Dictionary<string, Func<Task>>()
{
    {"!example", () => MessageEventArgs.Channel.SendMessage("HelloWorld") }
}

await myDict[e.Message.Text]();
```